# How to display a server side validation error on view page

Tags: ajax, grails, sammy.js

As i'm working on grails framework but not using controller.My application is "Single Page Application".I dont want to reload my page so I have written service i.e RegistrationService with Ajax calling. So i'm using knockout for data-binding.Database using is postgresql .
I have a view page where i'm having an email field. When i'm entering a duplicate  email id and clicking save button then i can see a validation error i.e "Email has already been taken" but even if i'm writing a unique id then also i'm getting the same validation error.This is because its going in error condition in modalModal.js page, So I'm not getting how to fix this problem.I just want when i enter unique id and click save button then it should not given validation error.

```
_newCostingpage.gsp  (my view page)

    <div id="light" class="white_content" style="color: black;">
    <form action="#/cart" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="${grailsApplication.config.serverURL}"/>
    <p><label>first name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="firstName"
             class="formElement" data-bind='value: firstName'/></label></p>
    <p><label>last name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="lastName" 
              class="formElement" data-bind='value: lastName' /></label></p>
    <p><label>organisation: <input name="organisation" class="formElement" data-
              bind='value: organisation' /></label></p>
<p><label>email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input name="email" class="formElement" data-bind='value: email' /></label><label 
         id="errorDiv"></label></p>
<p><label>password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="password" name="password"
         class="formElement" data-bind='value: password' /></label></p>
 <p><label style="margin-left: -37px;">confirm password:</label> <input
        type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="formElement" data-bind='value:
        confirmPassword' /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="register"/></p>
</form>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';clearBox();">Close</a>
        </div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
    </div>

Domain class :-\

  class Registration {
String firstName
String lastName
String organization
String email
String password
String confirmPassword

static constraints = {
    firstName(nullable:false)
    lastName(nullable:true)
    organization(blank:false)
    email(nullable:false,email:true,unique:true)
    password(blank:false)
    confirmPassword(blank:false)
               }
            }
```

modalModal.js

```
var ratPack = $.sammy(function() {
this.post('#/cart', function() {
    var firstname = this.params['firstName'];
    var lastName = this.params['lastName'];
    var organisation = this.params['organisation'];
    var email = this.params['email'];
    var password = this.params['password'];
    var confirmPassword = this.params['confirmPassword'];
    var baseurl = this.params['url'];
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url :'http://localhost:9191/guido-rest-
                          resource/api/registration/'+firstname+'/'+lastName+'/'+email,
        success : function() {
            alert("success:");
        },
        error:function(){
           $('#errorDiv').text("Email has already been taken");
        }
    });
    });
      });
        $(function() {
       ratPack.run();
        });
        function clearBox(){
       $('.formElement').val("");
       }


   RegistrationResource.groovy

         package common.rest.resourcepl
         import static org.grails.jaxrs.response.Responses.*
         import javax.ws.rs.Consumes
         import javax.ws.rs.GET
         import javax.ws.rs.Produces
         import javax.ws.rs.Path
       import javax.ws.rs.PathParam
       import javax.ws.rs.POST
      import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
      import common.servicepl.RegistrationService
     @Path('/api/registration')
       class RegistrationResource {
   @GET
   @Produces('text/plain')
   String getRegistrationRepresentation() {
    'Registration'
    }
   def registrationService;
    @POST
    @Path('/{firstname}/{lastName}/{email}')
    Response create(@PathParam('firstname') String firstname,
                @PathParam('lastName') String lastName,
                @PathParam('email') String email) {
                return  
        RegistrationService().createRegistration(firstname,lastName,email);
  }
     }

     RegistrationService.groovy

         package common.servicepl
         import common.persistencepl.Registration
         class RegistrationService {
              def createRegistration(String firstName,String lastName,String email) {
        println "Inside Registration Service"
        def reg = new Registration();
        reg.firstName = firstName;
        reg.lastName = lastName;
        reg.password = "asdf";
        reg.confirmPassword = "asdf";
        reg.email = email;
        reg.organization = "fasdf";
        if(reg.save([flush:true])){
           return true
        }
        else
        {
          return false
        }
          }
         }
```

Comment: when you call a service from your same application, do not speficy the full path like `http://localhost...`, Specify it relative to your current page `/api/registration...`

Answer (score 1):

Server should include server side errors in the response.

Make those error messages a property of the viewmodal, and bind that to properly styled html segment.

Also, when you call a service from your same application, do not speficy the full path like `http://localhost...`, Specify it relative to your current page `/api/registration...`

Comment: If you check my view page there i have created an id="errorDiv". Used this id and made a error property in modalModal.js

Comment: You'd be better off re-rendering the form server side with checks for errors. Look up `<g:hasErrors />` and `<g:renderErrors />`

Comment: @JamesKleeh : thanx for reply .
But what i want to know that through request i'm able save my data values into the database but in case of response , its not property working out . Thats why i'm getting into error property of modalModal.js . But why its happening and why i'm not getting my alert as "success"?

Comment: @BuddhiP : I'm calling a service from my diff application.

Comment: @BuddhiP  : If i try to call the service within one application ,then i'm getting my answer i.e success .  If i have servicein diff application then it is not working out?
Any possible solution to do this ?

Comment: @PathFinder, I'm sorry, what is 'diff' application?

Comment: @BuddhiP: Sorry for writing short form.Diff stands for Different application . I'm running that application on port 9191 as you can see my code modalModal.js and my grails project on local host 8080.

Answer (score 0):

In grails controller you should write:

```
if (!beanName.hasErrors() && beanName.validate()) {
        // TODO 
   } else {
         render status: Constants.SC_VALIDATION_FAILED, view: "viewName", model: [beanName: beanName]
}
```

and in view:

```
<div>
 <g:hasErrors bean="${beanName}">
   <div class="errors">
     <g:renderErrors bean="${beanName}" as="list"/>
   </div>
 </g:hasErrors>
</div>
```